# Adding a non-reflecting stationary set

Tags: set-theory, forcing

I'm reading Cummings' chapter in the handbook of set theory, and I have a question regarding the following forcing+assertion:

**"** *Let* $κ = cf(κ) ≥ ω_2$.
*We define a forcing poset* $P$ *which aims to add a non-reflecting stationary set
of cofinality* $ω$ *ordinals in* $κ$, *that is to say a stationary* $S ⊆ κ ∩ Cof(ω)$ *such*
*that* $S ∩ α$ *is non-stationary for all* $α ∈ κ ∩ Cof(> ω)$. $p ∈ P$ *if and only if* $p$
*is a function such that*

$1.$ $dom(p) < κ$,  $ran(p) ⊆ 2$.

$2.$ If $p(α) = 1$, $cf(α) = ω.$

$3.$ if $β ≤ dom(p)$ and $cf(β) > ω$ *then there exists a set* $c ⊆ β$ *club in* $β$
such that $∀α∈c   
     p(α)= 0.$

*It is easy to see that* $P$ *is countably closed, and that it adds the characteristic
function of a stationary subset of* $κ$.**"**

[ This is **Example 6.5** and its on page 21 in the link from his site: http://www.math.cmu.edu/users/jcumming/papers/repaper_finished_june_2008.pdf ]

I dont see why the generic function is a characteristic of a stationary, any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the same argument as for showing that a ($\kappa$)-Cohen real is a stationary set:

Given any name for a club $\dot C \subseteq \kappa$ and any condition $p$, define a decreasing sequence $\langle p_n \rangle_{n \in \omega}$ below $p$, and a strictly increasing sequence of ordinals $\langle \alpha_n \rangle_{n \in \omega}$ so that $p_n \Vdash \alpha_n \in \dot C$ and $\alpha_{n+1} > \operatorname{dom} p_n$. Then any lower bound $q$ of $\langle p_n \rangle_{n \in \omega}$ forces that $\alpha := \sup \alpha_n \in \dot C$, because $\dot C$ is forced to be club. But note that in fact $q := \bigcup_{n \in \omega} p_n$ is a lower bound of $\langle p_n \rangle$ and $\alpha \notin \operatorname{dom} q$. Also, $\alpha$ has countable cofinality. So we can extend $q$ to $r := q \cup \{ (\alpha,1) \}$. But then $r \Vdash \alpha \in \dot S \cap \dot C$ where $\dot S$ is the name for the generic.